# Comparing two variables in JSON File Python

Tags: python, api

Quick question - I have a Python Application that retrieves data from an API and implements it within a json file, and I programmed that functionality well. Now, I need to read the data, and if two variables in the .json file are greater than or less than, I need to recall the web url and recall the web request and add to the .json file.

So I guess I need to convert elements in the json file to Python objects, and then do an operation?

How would I go about doing this in Python?

Comment: You need to load the JSON file as a Python dictionary and go from there. Without an example of your JSON data it's impossible to be any more specific than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

with open("file.json", "r") as f:
    json_obj = json.loads(f.read())

# compare values in 'json_obj' here
```

Example 1:

```
if json_obj["key"] > 3.14:
    do_something()
```

Example 2:

```
if json_obj["key"]["sub_key"] > 3.14:
    do_something()
```

Comment: How would I go about comparing the values? can you give me an example?

Comment: edited it, how about now?

Comment: So if I wanted to compare two json objects against each other, it would be json_obj[number] > json_obj[anothervalue]?